# Output largest element on the right for each element in an Array

Tags: javascript, loops

Consider an input of `Arr1 = [4, 6, 3, 9, 11, 5]`

I want a function which takes the array as input. 
For each element in the array, it should output first higher value on its right.

Example Output : **4 - 6 ; 6 - 9 ; 3 - 9 ; 9 - 11 , 11 - -1 , 5 - -1**

**Requirement** :  I want to implement this without using nested for loops.

---

```
for (i = 0,k = Arr1.length;i< k;i ++){
            var val = false;
            for(j=i+1;j<k;j++){

                while(Arr1[i] < Arr1[j] ){

                        console.log( Arr1[i] + " --" + Arr1[j]);
                        val = true;
                        break;
                }
                if(val){break;}
            }
            if( !val){
                console.log( Arr1[i] + " --" +" -1");
            }

        }
```

---

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where exactly are you stuck? Can you show us some code to work with?

Comment: Please add more code, so we can help you (and understand you)

Comment: @icke  Hope my problem is understandable  now .

Comment: @AvinashK It's good that you've added your code, but there's still no question in your question. Does your code not work? Does it not do what it's supposed to? How does its results differ from the expected? Etc, etc.

Comment: Your `while` loop is pretty useless. Why not simply use an `if`? The nested `for` loop can probably also be reduced away.

Comment: @Biffen : The code is working .  I am  not satisfied with the way the code was.. I need some improvements. And I have edited the question please check .

Comment: @Xufox : Yes what you have stated is absolutely correct. I have already implemented one with if condition but I haven't posted that here . As you have said I want to reduce the use of nested loops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example of how to do it. The idea is to iterate through your array, then look at every element after the one you're currently looking at until you find one that is greater. The greater element (or -1 by default) is pushed into a second array for storage.

```
var Arr1 = [4, 6, 3, 9, 11, 5];
var Arr2 = [];
for (var i=0;i<Arr1.length;i++) {
    var biggerNumber = -1;
    for (var j=i+1;j<Arr1.length;j++) {
        if (Arr1[j]>Arr1[i]) {
            biggerNumber = Arr1[j];
            break;
        }
    }
    Arr2.push(biggerNumber);
}
//output: 
for(var i=0;i<Arr1.length;i++) {
    console.log(Arr1[i]+" -- "+Arr2[i]);
}
```

**Updated answer**:

```
var Arr1 = [4, 6, 3, 9, 11, 5];
var stack=[];
Arr1.forEach(function(i){
    if (stack.length==0 || i<=stack[stack.length-1]) {
        stack.push(i);
    } else {
        while(stack.length>0 && i>stack[stack.length-1]) {
            console.log(i);
            stack.pop();
        }
        stack.push(i);
    }
});
stack.forEach(function(){console.log(-1);});
```

Why it's better: The inner loop performs `Arr1.length` operations total, so it's still running in O(n). How to implement that without nested loops I still have no idea.

Comment: This is clear to me . Using this I can remove my break statement and I can  push -1 value without using another if condition. But I want to implement this without using Nested loops . Any Idea ?

Comment: Sorry, I can't think of a way to do this with just one loop other than hiding a second inner loop in a function or using a built-in function that performs a loop internally.

Comment: Is there anything we can do using Stacks in this problem ?

Comment: I don't see how that would help. I'm eager to know if there is a solution, but I can't think of one.

Comment: I was asked this question in an interview yesterday . I told him a logic which is very near to my solution above. He asked me not to use nested loops.  I too couldn't think of a better way. When I asked him how will you improve this his exact reply was this : "Using stacks . Try it".

Comment: Well, I can think of a way to do it in O(n), but I still don't know how to do it without nested loops.